# With Quarto how do I see intermediate md files that lead to revealjs presentation?

Tags: r, quarto

I think that quarto renders to markdown on the way to making Revealjs:

```
qmd > knitr/jupyter  > md >  pandoc > Revealjs
```

I am curious to see how details like

```yaml
format:
  revealjs:
    incremental: true
```

and

```
    ::: {.incremental}
    
    - Eat spaghetti
    - Drink wine
    
    :::
```

are represented in the temporary/intermediate markdown file.

In R, I tried:

```
quarto::quarto_render("slides.qmd", output_format="markdown")
```

and the "incremental" details are stripped out.

Is there a temporary/intermediate markdown file created on the way to revealjs?  If so, how can I see it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**

You can use `debug = TRUE` in `quarto_render`

```
quarto::quarto_render("slides.qmd", output_format="markdown", debug = TRUE)
```

**Option 2**

use `keep-md: true` in under `execute` in yaml

```
---
title: "Untitled"
format:
  revealjs:
    incremental: true
execute:
  keep-md: true
---

## Quarto

::: {.incremental}

- Eat spaghetti
- Drink wine

:::
```

Then either you can click the **render** button in Rstudio or run this (what you have tried previously).

```r
quarto::quarto_render("slides.qmd", output_format="markdown")
```

Comment: TIL: quarto is just passing YAML to Pandoc.  Thank you.